# Question about tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I need some `table` in LaTeX. As you can see, my LaTeX code is following

```
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{7.6pt}
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{tabular}{l|m{7cm}}
\hline
\hline
Workloads & Applications  \\
\hline
\hline
mix-1 & mcf, libquantum, \\
\hline
mix-2 & sphinx3, soplex, \\
\hline
mix-3 & omnetpp, xalancbmk, \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}
```

Actually, I could not understand `array` packages. I meant it's `m{2.5cm}`'s use method.
I want to align a text in right side into vertical center like left side.

Can you help me? Some explain in other site make me confused because I'm not expert in LaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Your table seems to work fine if you comment out the `setlength{\extrarowheight}{7.6pt}` and include `\usepackage{array}` in the preamble.
`

Comment: use `\footnotesize` as a switch and not as an environment

Answer (score 4):

In terms of vertically centering the content in your `tabular` cells, you don't need to set `\extrarowheight`. However, using `m{<len>}` (where `<len>` is any recognized TeX length) becomes useful when your right-hand column has a little more substance to it (that is, it is longer).

If you're interested in more vertical padding around the entries, modify `\arraystretch` instead. It provides a factor with which the rows are stretched/expanded:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}% array stretch factor
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{tabular}{l|p{7cm}}
  \hline
  \hline
  Workloads & Applications  \\
  \hline
  \hline
  mix-1 & mcf, libquantum, \\
  \hline
  mix-2 & sphinx3, soplex, \\
  \hline
  mix-3 & omnetpp, xalancbmk, \\
  \hline
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{document}
```

For more information on padding of cell entries with a `tabular` (both horizontally and vertically), see [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-padding-in-tables).

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is your premable. If you include `\usepackage{array}` this compiles.  Also, you should move the `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{7.6pt}` to be within a group (unless you want this to apply to **all** tables), you get:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{footnotesize} \setlength{\extrarowheight}{7.6pt}
\begin{tabular}{l|m{7cm}}
\hline
\hline
Workloads & Applications  \\
\hline
\hline
mix-1 & mcf, libquantum, \\
\hline
mix-2 & sphinx3, soplex, \\
\hline
mix-3 & omnetpp, xalancbmk, \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want both columns to be vertically centered then you have to use

```
\begin{tabular}{m{1.5cm}|m{7cm}}
```

which yields the following. The extra vertical space above the data is coming from your setting of `\extrarowheight`.

[image]